# I am showing aspx page(Add Item form) inside jquery modal, whenever I upload an image the page refreshes and loads as a normal webpage

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net

I have 2 files :-

1. Items.aspx with the list of items in a grid view, A button(to open a form for adding new item), and a div with id testing.

code Inside Items.aspx

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Basic.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Items.aspx.cs" Inherits="FlowerShopAdminPanel.Items" %>

            <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
            </asp:Content>
            <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="header" runat="server">
                <div id="dvGrid" class="container">
            <!-- This contains the gridview -->
                </div>
                <div id="testing"></div>



            <script>
                function openDialog($itemid,$categoryid) {
                    $('#testing').dialog({
                        modal: true,
                        dialogClass: "no-close",
                        open: function () {
                            $(this).load('AddItem.aspx?itemid=' + $itemid+'&categoryid='+$categoryid);
                            $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", ui.dialog | ui).hide();
                        },
                        height: 500,
                        width: 500,
                        title: 'Add Item'
                    });
                }
            </script>
            <style>
                .image {
                    height: 30vh;
                }

                .no-close .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
                    display: none;
                }
            </style>
        </asp:Content>
```

This loads a form to add item in a jquery modal. we can upload image to that item using a Button . Above function is on another aspx form in which I am

2. AddItem.aspx

   ```
        <div>
   <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Category Name"></asp:Label>
       <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="category_ddl"></asp:DropDownList>
   </div>   

       <div> 
           <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Item Name"> </asp:Label>
           <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="itemname_txt"></asp:TextBox>
       </div> 
       <div>
           <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Description"></asp:Label>
           <asp:TextBox runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="5" Columns="50" ID="description_txt"></asp:TextBox>
       </div>

       <div>
           <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Main Image"></asp:Label>
           <asp:FileUpload runat="server"  ID="mainimage_fileupload"/><br />

           <asp:Image runat="server" ID="mainimage_img" Visible="false"  />

           <asp:Button runat="server" ID="fileupload_btn" Text="Upload" OnClick="fileupload_btn_Click" />

           <asp:Label runat="server" ID="filename_lbl" Visible="false" ForeColor="Red" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
       </div>

       <div>
           <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Active"> </asp:Label>
           <asp:CheckBox  runat="server" ID="isActive_chk"/>
       </div>

        <div>
           <asp:Button runat="server"  ID="addItem_btn" Text="Add Item" OnClick="addItem_btn_Click"/>
            <asp:Button runat="server"  ID="cancel_btn" Text="Cancel" OnClick="cancel_btn_Click"/>
       </div>   

   </div>
   </form>
   ```

Whenever I upload the image it opens up as a normal aspx page. Basically, Whenever the aspx page is refreshed, it opens up as a normal web page. I always want to open it in the jQuery modal.

Please help in resolving this issue.

Thank you

Comment: You could load the AddItem.aspx in an Iframe which is placed in the modal body

Comment: Please provide some resources or an example for doing this, it will be really helpful.  Thanks

Comment: You can find a similar solution here http://www.bootply.com/61676

Comment: try adding ajax in your page?